# How to check that data selector is not on the screen using puppeteer

Tags: dom, element, puppeteer, chai

I need to check that data-selector is visible only in case I press one button. On front end it works that one button runs some code and there appeare one fa-lock icon. When I press another button than this icon disappeare. When I try to inspect element in console for developer I see that using this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-selector="private-inbox-lock-icon"]')
```

there is empty NodeList with length 0 when icon is not on the screen and NodeList is e.g. NodeList [i.fal.fa-lock.lock-icon] with length 1 whene icon is on the screen. So this is proof that it works. But I am not able to make chai assertion condition to check this in backend.

I get all selectors from the screen

```
const lockIcons = await 
World.page.$$('[data-selector="private-inbox-lock-icon"]');
```

But I am not able to set up condition when selector is not on the screen cause await alway returns me an array of elements. ElementHandle type. So this is alway full of data...

```
expect(lockIcons).to.not.be.empty; - true when Icon on the screen 
expect(lockIcons).to.be.empty; - doesn´t work cause lockIcons is not empty anytime.......
```

How to set up condition when lockIcons is always not null, no empty even if data-selector is not on the screen... I don´t just got it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might take a look at [waitForSelector](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.19.0&show=api-pagewaitforselectorselector-options) method, in case there are CSS properties like `display`

`const node = await page.waitForSelector('[data-selector="private-inbox-lock-icon"]', { visible: true });`

it will return `false` when `display` property will be set to `none`

this should work if there's only one element matching your selector

Other scenario:
if you expecting element to be removed from DOM then simple

`await page.$('[data-selector="private-inbox-lock-icon"]')` will return `null` because there's no element matching selector

then from chai docs:
`expect(node).to.be.null;`

Comment: Hi @domlas, thanks. I have already tried this solution and seems to work. Look at this  code:
`try {
        await World.page.waitForSelector('[data-selector="private-inbox-lock-icon"]'), {
          hidden: true,
          timeout: 500
        });
      } catch (e) {
        if (e instanceof TimeoutError)
          console.log('Icon is not visible good.');
      }`

Comment: @MartinF in your code you used one close parenthesis too much after selector
but the conception is ok -> TimeoutError is thrown if no match is found by `waitForSelector`